# splitting Interval Date in character and casting into Date in R

Tags: r, date, character, intervals

I have below Date column in character (from ENTSO-E platform).  I want to convert into Date and extract the end part of this Interval ([1] "01.01.2021 00:00 - **01.01.2021 01:00**").  I am receiving error "character string in unambiguous format".  Any suggestions how can I extract the second part of the interval that is in character format to a Date variable in R?

```
head(date)
```

- "01.01.2021 00:00 - 01.01.2021 01:00"
- "01.01.2021 01:00 - 01.01.2021 02:00"
- "01.01.2021 02:00 - 01.01.2021 03:00"
- "01.01.2021 03:00 - 01.01.2021 04:00"
- "01.01.2021 04:00 - 01.01.2021 05:00"
- "01.01.2021 05:00 - 01.01.2021 06:00"

> ```
> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
>   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.POSIXct(gsub("^.* - (.*)", "\\1", x), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
# [1] "2021-01-01 01:00:00 CET" "2021-01-01 02:00:00 CET" "2021-01-01 03:00:00 CET" "2021-01-01 04:00:00 CET"
# [5] "2021-01-01 05:00:00 CET"
```

**sample data**

```
x <- c("01.01.2021 00:00 - 01.01.2021 01:00",
       "01.01.2021 01:00 - 01.01.2021 02:00",
       "01.01.2021 02:00 - 01.01.2021 03:00",
       "01.01.2021 03:00 - 01.01.2021 04:00",
       "01.01.2021 04:00 - 01.01.2021 05:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `tidyverse` in combination with `lubridate`s `dmy_hm` function:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(date, c("a", "date"), " - ") %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy_hm(date), .keep="used")
```

```
date               
  <dttm>             
1 2021-01-01 01:00:00
2 2021-01-01 02:00:00
3 2021-01-01 03:00:00
4 2021-01-01 04:00:00
5 2021-01-01 05:00:00
6 2021-01-01 06:00:00
```